# Searching a string for keywords with mutiple methods

Tags: java, arrays, string, eclipse

My main method is written to split the string zach into separate arrays, capitalize, and to remove commas and periods. I am trying to write the isNonStopMethod to locate certain stop words which are ("THE", "BE", "TO", "OF", "AND", "A", "IN", "THAT' "I", "IT", "ON", "IN", "BUT", "IS", "WITH") found in string zach. I need help searching for these key words in the string.

```
 package zk;

 public class Class {

    public boolean isNonStopWord(int[] nums, int value)
    {
    ("THE", "BE", "TO", "OF", "AND", "A", "IN", "THAT",
            "I", "IT", "ON", "IN", "BUT", "IS", "WITH");
            return false;
    }


    public static void main(String [] args) {

            String zach = ("Amazon offered up more answers Thursday about what"
                            + " caused a bunch of websites to fail two days ago. According "
                            + "to a postmortem by the company's cloud services business, "
                            + "around 9:37 a.m. PT Tuesday an Amazon worker incorrectly"
                            + " punched in a command while trying to debug an issue. "
                            + "That command shut down a large set of servers at Amazon Web "
                            + "Services' Northern Virginia site, causing a domino effect of"
                            + " problems. Other services that relied on those S3 cloud"
                            + " storage servers were disrupted. Also, removing so much "
                            + "server capacity required a full system restart, which then "
                            + "took longer than expected, AWS said. The sites affected "
                            + "included Quora, Imgur, IFTTT, Giphy and Slack. Amazon was "
                            + "able to fix the issue by about 2 p.m. PT.");
            zach = zach.replace(",","");
            zach = zach.replace(".","");
    zach = zach.toUpperCase();
    String [] strings = zach.split(" ");
    for (String s1: strings) {
            System.out.println(s1);

    }
    }



 }
```

Comment: Try `String.indexOf();`.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Also to test your regex, you can use https://regex101.com/ which I found very helpful.